# Block doesn't show up in the entity reference UI

Tags: blocks, 9, views

I have an Entity Reference field, whose "type of item to reference" is **block**.

I have a View that creates a block called *staff list* but when I edit content that uses that field, I can't get it to present *staff list* as an option?

Why is this block not selectable? Surely all 'blocks' should be reference-able this way?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field is referencing block config entities. Those exists only for blocks placed in the block layout. If Views creates a block then this is a derivative of a views block plugin and not yet a configured block. You could place the block in block layout, then it shows up in the entity reference select UI. But this is not a good idea. This will cause an error if you remove the configuration and still have references in content.

So better use a different field type. You can place block plugins directly in node fields. See [Display custom module block in page content](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/309310/display-custom-module-block-in-page-content). Or the View directly in a node field, without using a block display. There are a few modules for this:

https://www.drupal.org/project/eva

https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield

Comment: Thanks. (I'm now recalling this might be why I abandoned D8 years ago!) So I have a paragraph type that wants to offer authors the opportunity to put something in their para. This might be a custom block, a block generated from any number of modules including a view. Blocks used to be a solid reusable concept. But I think you're suggesting I'd need to add one field for every type of block now? This seems to un-do the whole concept of Blocks?

Comment: Ah. yes, it was. Just found my question from 5 years ago https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198623/how-to-create-a-field-that-references-a-views-block-display-in-d8  The block_field project looks promising, though it's a lot more of a headache for authors. Maybe I'll go back to placing the block in a non-rendered region (though I remember there were some other problems with that..).

Comment: OK, if you want to create a paragraph type which allows the user to place a block generated from any number of modules including Views then your question is a duplicate of the linked question asked recently.

Comment: All three modules have their use cases and there are more modules out there. My favorite is the EVA module if you don't want to give the authors a headache.